# Connect Smart Card to Web Application

Tags: c#, java, javascript, php, smartcard

I need to build a web application where the user connects a smart card and throught the authentitication program, he logs on to the server and see the info.

[image]

My questions are very simple, what language should i use? What is the best API? And if could share more information about this subject i will be grateful.

Thank you all,

Gonçalo Moura

Comment: create an applet which reads the smartcard and call it via javascript

Answer (score 2):

Since your digram already decipts the Html form , that means you are clear with the client side.
For server side coding refer the link http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/which_serverside_technology.html .
Hope it helps !

Comment: first of all thank you for the quick answer, about the digram that i posted was something that i found over the internet to point out more what i am going to do. About the languages i have some knowledge of them, the point is what is the better one to connect with this technology, i searched over and i didn't find something usefull. Maybe its the key words that im using, im kinda lost what to search for

Comment: this diagram represents some API for jsp i think, my question is whats the best one you guys use or used and which language should i use. Because i need to get some info from the client-side, and if its "true" then logs in into the server.

Comment: Yeah you can go for HTML javascript at the front end and some new technologies if you want an enriched User Interface (such as Twitter Bootstrap etc) cause you are focusing on Web Application right and not on Mobile App . For server side you can opt for Java or Php or .Net ,the one which you are comfortable with.